# if a certain columns's var is lower then n i want to drop that column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
train = train.columns.apply(lambda x : train.drop([x],axis=1) if train[x].var() <100)
```

if a certain columns's var is lower then n i want to drop that column. 
let say column x's var is lower then 100 then I want to drop the column

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 2):

In pandas we can do

```
df=df.loc[:,~df.var(axis=0).lt(100)].copy()
```

Comment: Beat me to the answer, nice job! Also good to see that they are not reassigning it to the same dataframe and vectoring the answer rather than using the "silver bullet"

Comment: Why the `.copy()`?

Comment: @AMC in case he need additional modify with the df, then will have the setcopy warning https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas